# Difference between synchronized(this) and few synchronized methods of class

Tags: java, synchronized

In Programming Interviews Exposed book (Wrox publications), code for Producer consumer problem uses 'synchronized' keyword for each of produce() and consume() methods inside a class called IntBuffer. Is this different than using synchronized(this) inside each of those methods ? The book says, "When a thread is busy waiting in produce(), no thread can enter consume() because methods are synchronized." I don't feel that makes sense for the code in the book because, when a thread is busy waiting in produce(), no thread can enter produce(). However other thread can enter consume() which shatters the idea of mutual exclusion. The methods produce and consume should both entirely be synchronized right ?

Code in the book:

```
public class IntBuffer
{
    private int index;
    private int[] buffer = new int[8];

    // Function called by producer thread
    public synchronized void produce(int num) {
        while(index == buffer.length - 1) {
            try { wait();}
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
        buffer[index++] = num;
        notifyAll();
    }

    // Function called by consumer thread
    public synchronized int consume() {
        while(index == 0) {
            try { wait();}
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
        int ret = buffer[--index];
        notifyAll();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marking a method `synchronized` synchronizes on `this` just like a `synchronized (this)` block. It's not synchronizing on the method or anything like that.

Comment: `The methods produce and consume should both entirely be synchronized right ?`  Normally, yes, both the producer and consumer need to synchronize on the same object.  I think we'd need to see the exact code to be sure though.

Comment: [*"A `synchronized` method acquires a monitor before it executes. For an instance method, the monitor associated with `this` (the object for which the method was invoked) is used."*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are the same.

```
private synchronized void foo() {}

private void foo2() {
 synchronized(this){
 }
}
```

They will do the exact same as both monitor the instance which they are called from.

A good tutorial can be found in the blog of Jakob Jenkov
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html#java-synchronized-example

Happy coding!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest you remove the last line of your answer to make it more in line with site style. (If everyone added an EDIT line when they fixed a typo, practically every answer would have them.)

Answer (score 1):

Using synchronized(this) requires the calling thread to take the same lock as when it calls an instance method using the synchronized modifier on the method. There are some differences in what bytecode is generated but that's a pretty low-level distinction.

The purpose of the synchronized keyword is to protect shared state from concurrent access. The produce and consume methods use the same internal state so it's reasonable that they are both protected by the same lock.

The posted code looks well-done, my only nitpick is i would let the methods throw InterruptedException instead of catching it. Both the produce and consume methods require the calling thread to acquire the lock on the instance that the method is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is this different than using synchronized(this) inside each of those methods ? 
A : No, it is not different, by using block (synchronize(this) you can synchronize just part of your code, not the whole method. 
For example :

```
public void m1(){
// some code
synchronized(this){ 
// thread-safe code 
}
```

Comment: I want to synchronize both the methods simultaneously and not individually. Will synchronize(this) not serve my purpose because, 'this' is current instance right ? synchronize(this) should lock the entire instance i.e only one method out of produce() and consume() will be processed by a thread at a time.

Comment: `synchronize(this)` will work exactly the same as synchronizing an instance method, which is exactly as you have now.  The code you posted is correct, please try to understand it before you make changes.  See EJP's answer.

Comment: Yes, true. You would need to synchronize on different objects, or you might use another concurrency primitives to signal from producer to suppler and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

> Is this different than using synchronized(this) inside each of those methods?

No.

> The book says, "When a thread is busy waiting in produce(), no thread can enter consume() because methods are synchronized." I don't feel that makes sense for the code in the book because, when a thread is busy waiting in produce(), no thread can enter produce(). However other thread can enter consume() which shatters the idea of mutual exclusion.

That's not correct. Both methods are synchronized on the same object, so only one thread can be in either method, unless `wait()` is called, which it is, which releases the lock.

> The methods produce and consume should both entirely be synchronized right?

Yes, and you said they are. Unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: I agree with the "unclear" part, the code the OP posted appears to be correct.  I'll just emphasize that `wait()` releases the lock.  That allows code inside producer to stop and code inside consumer to start up again, which I think is where the OP might have mislead themselves.